# Visualforce auto-completion in Force.com IDE

Tags: visualforce, force.com, ide, eclipse

Where to enable auto-completion for Visualforce code in Eclipse?

I am using Force.com IDE as Eclipse plugin. Some time ago auto-completion used to work fine when coding a Visualforce page. Now it does not work and I can't find where to enable it again.

Versions: Force.com IDE: 30; 
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers: Kepler Service Release 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The auto-complete feature for the Visualforce code is not currently supported by the force.com IDE. However there is an Idea on the IdeaExchange: [IDE: Autocomplete for Apex and Visualforce code](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrptAAC)

Alternative you can use an eclipse plugin [Rich Visualforce Editor](https://github.com/ajayhada/Rich-VisualForce-Editor) which have VisualForce tag and attribute assistance or just use a [Developer Console](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developer_Console) that supports it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info, mast0r. I was 100% sure I used Visualforce auto-completion before. That's strange. I'll try Rich Visualforce editor.